# Android NavigationRail Show multiple label lines for item text

Tags: android, navigation

I'm developing a NavigationRail and I wanted to display the text of each item in two lines, as show in this official example, but it keeps getting ellipsized in the end. I've tried to redefine the applying style but nothing seems to work.

[image: Sample of item label in two lines from Official doc]

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `itemMaxLines` Can you try and see this attribute in the navigation rail XML?

Comment: @Kartik thanks but It doesn't work. I'm inheriting from _Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationRailView.PrimarySurface_ style, in case it helps.

Comment: Are you using another language then english? Does the string have spaces or dashes in them i.e. a natural point to break?

Comment: Yes, it's multi language, and the line I'm trying to watch written in two lines has an explicit line jump: "Edit \n user" and no dashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Navigation rail - Material Design](https://material.io/components/navigation-rail/android#using-navigation-rail) documentation it seems that there is no an official way to set multiple lines for an item text. But you can achieve this with a simple workaround like in the below example:

**1**.Define the `NavigationRailView` in xml like the below:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigationrail.NavigationRailView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_rail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_rail_menu"/>
```

where `@menu/navigation_rail_menu` contains the below sample menu items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_all_files"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="All\nFiles" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_recent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Recent\nFiles" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_all_pictures"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="All\nPictures" />
</menu>
```

**2**.And for each item change the Max number of lines in a programmatically way like in the below example:

```
//get the NavigationRailView
NavigationRailView navigationRailView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_rail);

//menu item 1
NavigationBarItemView item1 = navigationRailView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_all_files);
BaselineLayout item1BaselineLayout = item1.findViewById(R.id.navigation_bar_item_labels_group);
setItemMaxLines(item1BaselineLayout, 2);

//menu item 2
NavigationBarItemView item2 = navigationRailView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_recent);
BaselineLayout item2BaselineLayout = item2.findViewById(R.id.navigation_bar_item_labels_group);
setItemMaxLines(item2BaselineLayout, 2);

//menu item 3
NavigationBarItemView item3 = navigationRailView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_all_pictures);
BaselineLayout item3BaselineLayout = item3.findViewById(R.id.navigation_bar_item_labels_group);
setItemMaxLines(item3BaselineLayout, 2);
```

where `setItemMaxLines()` is a helper function to change for each Item the `MaxLines`:

```
private void setItemMaxLines(BaselineLayout baselineLayout, int maxLines){
    if(baselineLayout!=null){
        for(int i=0; i<baselineLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
            View child = baselineLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if(child instanceof MaterialTextView){
                ((MaterialTextView)child).setMaxLines(maxLines);
                ((MaterialTextView)child).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: navigation_rail]